# How to iterate values in set<pair<int,int> >st by using set<pair<int,int> >::iterator it?

Tags: c++, stl, iteration

I am using pair in set and want to print values and my compiler always shows errors in "code 1" but it runs successfully in "code 2" .

I know that, these two procedure are same to access a set without a pair, but i faced problem using pair into a set.

I am using Windows 10 + Intel and using "codeblocks" IDE.

code 1:

```
set < pair< int,int> >::iterator it;
for(it=st.begin();it!=st.end();it++){
    cout << *(it.first) << " " << *(it.second) << endl ;//error shows here
}
```

code 2:

```
set< pair < int,int > >::iterator it;
for(it : st){
  cout << it.first << " " << it.second << endl ;
}
```

In "code 2", my program runs successfully but in "code 1" it shows error pointed to the commented line.

Comment: Where is your `main` function? What data are you testing this with? What's the error?

Comment: You might want to try `for (const auto& e : st) cout << e.first << " " << e.second...`.

Comment: Please try to create an [mcve] to show us. And if you get build errors, show us the errors. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem, `*(it.first)` tries to dereference `it.first`. And `it` doesn't have a member `first`.

Answer (score 3):

`it` is an iterator refering to a pair, In order to access the pair you need to dereference the iterator first.

```
cout << (*it).first << " " << (*it).second << endl ;
```

or better

```
cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl ;
```

EDIT: If you have `c++17` support.

```
for(auto [first, second] : st)
     std::cout<<first<<" "<<second;
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo Added.Thanks.